# Twitter widgets customization

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter

I'm doing a page here with Twitter widgets on the side. Well I'm really a newbie in using this widget and I don't have a single idea on customizing it this is how far I've gone. First it will appear like this:

[image]

Names will appear one by one every 30 seconds from top going down background is transparent. Please disregard the borders (sorry I can't give a decent picture)

Well then What I wanted to do is for it to appear like this one:

[image]

Well from top to down it will become bottom to top displaying around 5 or 6 names and font is also adjusted smallest to biggest and positioned left and right alternating position.
Any Ideas? I would also appreciate if you could give me a little lesson here. :)

EDIT: I forgot HTML and I'm using a Javascript on this one.

for _slide looks like this:

```
 _slide: function(el) {
          var that = this;
          var height = getFirst(el).offsetHeight;
          if (this.runOnce) {
            new Animate(el, 'height', {
              from: 380,              
              to: height,
              time: 500,
              callback: function() 
              {
                that._fade.call(that, el);
              }
            }
            ).start();
          }
          return this;
        },
```

Thanks!

Comment: What twitter widget are you using? What platform are you using to build this?

Comment: HTML. Anyway I am not really familiar about this twitter widgets. All That I've done for now is to edit some codes I've found and customizing it. Though I'm having a hard time on how to figure it out.

Comment: Do you have the page publicly available?

Comment: Nope, page is still a work on progress. The twitter code is done by one of my colleagues I'm just helping out to know more about this one. :)

Comment: Ive added an answer that should help you buddy

Comment: Thanks man, will also try to figure this out. I will inform you whenever I solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay as you cant give any indication as to which widget you're using is difficult to help you reverse the order of the `<li>`'s specific to your widget, but here's how youd do it using jquery:

```
output = '<ul id="after">';

$($("li").get().reverse()).each(function() {
    output += '<li>'+$(this).text()+'</li>';
});

$('body').append(output+'</ul>');

$("#after li:even").css({"float":"left", "clear":"right"});
$("#after li:odd").css({"float":"right", "clear":"left"});

$("#after li:nth-child(2)").css({"width":"320px", "font-size":"90%"});
$("#after li:nth-child(3)").css({"width":"260px", "font-size":"80%"});
$("#after li:nth-child(4)").css({"width":"180px", "font-size":"70%"});
$("#after li:nth-child(5)").css({"width":"100px", "font-size":"60%"});
```

See the coded example here - http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/6MQew/1